# Extra parameter in link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

The following is a piece of code for index action. Can somebody explain me the use of a third parameter, :class => 'action show' in the link_to helper in line numbers 27,28 and 29. The code seems to work fine without this as well. I'm a rails rookie and thanks in advance.

```
<div class="subjects index">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <%= link_to("Add New Subject", '#', :class => 'action new') %>

  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subject.position %></td>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
      <td class="center">
      <%if(subject.pages!=nil)%>
      <%= subject.pages.size %>
      <% else %>
      <%= "1" %>
      <% end %>
      </td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("Show", {:action => "show",:id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
        <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
        <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It adds the class attribute to the html-tag.

So

```
<%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
```

will be rendered as:

```
<a href="#" class="action edit">Edit</a>
```

You can put any html options as third argument to the link_to helper.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to